# Keyboard shortcut in Notepad++ to upload file with nppFTP

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, shortcut

I love using Notepad++, but one thing that is constantly nagging me is that the nppFTP's synchronize folder functionality is a bit overkill, but that there seems to be no way to simply upload the current file to the current remote directory with a quick keyboard shortcut, on demand.

There are shortcut options defined for "focus nppFTP window" and even "About NppFTP", but I can find no option for simply clicking on the 'upload file' button.

I have opened a feature request for this small change ages ago, but noone seems to have noticed.

So, how can I add a shortcut myself? AutoHotKey, perhaps? (by emulating a click at the buttons coordinates, which seems easy to break?)

Maybe there's a easy way of modifying NppFTP's source or some XML file, so that I can assign a shortcut to that button?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed in which way(s) it can be done manually (screenshots are always nice). Anyhow, if there's a button in the main window of NP++, it may be exposed as a control with its own ClassNN. If so, it may be addressable (e.g. using [ControlClick](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @MCL .
I've uploaded a screenshot here: [http://gometa.org/autohotkeyNPP.png](http://gometa.org/autohotkeyNPP.png) .

As you can see, the upload button seems to have a class name of 'ToolbarWindow321', but so do all other buttons on that particular toolbar.

As a workaround, I tried to emulate a click on the button's corrdinates when N++ is in fullscreen, but it weirdly opens the 'Open File' dialog.

Comment: Where exactly is the button? Please mark it in the screenshot and include it in your question by editing it. What other ways are there for accessing the function? Try brainstorming and think of other ways to do it: Is there a menu entry? Can you focus the toolbar, then `{Tab}` to the button? Can the function be triggered via command line? Then, try to implement the method that fits best. As a last resort you could try clicking fixed coordinates as you've already tried, but be aware that they are relative to the active window by default (which is desirable normally), see `CoordMode`.

Answer (score 0):

How about uploading the script without Notepad++, but rather with AHK?
I wrote a little ftp function to do the job:

```
FtpUploadFile(host,user,pass,sourceFile,destPath:="/",mode:="ascii") {
    Static cmdFile := A_ScriptDir "\FTPCommands.txt"
    Static logFile := A_ScriptDir "\FTPLog.txt"    
    sourceFileFullPath := (InStr(sourceFile,"\") ? sourceFile : A_ScriptDir "\" sourceFile)
    FileDelete %cmdFile%
    FileAppend,  ; The comma is required in this case.
    ( LTrim
        open %host%
        %user%
        %pass%
        %mode%
        cd %destPath%
        put %sourceFileFullPath%
        ls -l
        quit
    ), %cmdFile%
    RunWait %comspec% /c ftp.exe -s:"%cmdFile%" >"%logFile%"
    FileDelete %cmdFile%  ; Delete for security reasons.
    FileRead, logTxt, %logFile%
    FileDelete %logFile%
    Return logTxt
}

F1:: ;press F1 to upload myFile.ahk and myFile.exe
    MsgBox % FtpUploadFile("my.host.com","username","password","myFile.ahk") ;uplaod a text baed file
    MsgBox % FtpUploadFile("my.host.com","username","password","myFile.exe","/","binary") ;upload a binary based file
Return
```

Remove the `MsgBox %` if you don't want the upload log.