# How to create a button to emulate F8 keystroke in NPP to pass code to NppToR

Tags: keyboard, notepad++

I want to create a button in NPP to emulate pressing F8 to pass selected lines of code from NPP to [NppToR](https://github.com/halpo/NppToR).

Following similar questions [[1](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23332/to-add-the-button-save-as-in-the-toolbar/2),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993702/keyboard-shortcut-in-notepad-to-upload-file-with-nppftp)], I tried adding this line (and its modifications) to `CustomizeToolbar.btn`, without success:

```
press F8,,,*G:F8,*G:F8
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.